# Add color to text which is dynamically added using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am adding text using -

```
jQuery(this).attr('data-label')
```

i want to **add grey color to this text**

```
jQuery(".classone").text('Email me when '+jQuery(this).attr('data-label')+' is back...');
```

is that possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can user .html method. Try below code.

1. if you want to gray text available in data-label then u can use this.

   `jQuery(".classone").html('Email me when <span style="color:gray;">'+jQuery(this).attr('data-label')+'</span> is back...');`
2. if you want to gray full text then u can use this.

   `jQuery(".classone").html('<span style="color:gray;">Email me when '+jQuery(this).attr('data-label')+' is back...</span>');`

Comment: Add full answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Hamendra you try this 2 options:

```
jQuery(".classone").html('Email me when <span style="color:gray;">'+jQuery(this).attr('data-label').attr('style','color:gray')+'</span> is back...');
```

or

```
jQuery(".classone").html('Email me when <span style="color:gray;">'+jQuery(this).attr({'data-label',style:'color:gray'})+'</span> is back...');
```

Comment: i have not tried this, but seems like it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
jQuery(".classone").html('Email me when <span style="color:gray;">'+jQuery(this).attr('data-label')+'</span> is back...');
```

Edited: changed text() with html()

Comment: Let me check with this

Comment: Not working it outputs - Email me when <span style="color:gray;">small</span> is back...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
jQuery(".classone").text('Email me when '+jQuery(this).attr('data-label')+' is back...').css("color", "grey")
```

You can use any color you want

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(".email_notification_header").html('Email me when <span style="color:#696969;">'+jQuery(this).attr('data-label')+'</span> is back...');
```